# What open source repos should I explore if I'm looking to build my first dApp on Solana?

Tags: opensource, beginner, resources

Looking for inspiration and tools I can reuse for my own creations

Answer (score 4):

You should checkout some of the stuff from Holaplex. github.com/holaplex

Comment: ^that looks solid! FWIW Alchemy also has some web3 dev resources (along with dev tooling + RPC endpoints) that are helpful for dev on Solana and any of the other chains they support - https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/best-web3-tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend Loris's tutorial: https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/
Repo: https://github.com/lorisleiva/solana-twitter/tree/first-build

Answer (score 2):

I found the [gemworks/gem-farm](https://github.com/gemworks/gem-farm) codebase a great place to draw inspiration for interacting with custom Solana programs using the JavaScript SDK.

It includes a lot of use of the Metaplex SDK which will have many SPL token account, balance, etc. lookups.